# private application for a private business in apple store

Tags: ios, xcode, privacy

I'm developing an app for my company, using firebase where I store some important business data.

My question is, can I publish the app on the App Store for free and create a login page where only the employees with specific account create from me can enter?
will apple accept an app like this?

otherwise how can I publish the app only for the company iPad?
my company have around 50 employees, I read about this Enterprise Development program but apparently require more than 100 employees.

thanks in advance for the help, sorry not I don't have much experience with app for private business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app with a limited audience like this won't be accepted for the App Store.

Your company will need to set up an Apple Business Manager account (which is free).

You can then make the app available only to their Apple Business Manager ID in App Store connect.  The app will still go through review but it won't be visible on the public App Store.

There is a [WWDC 2020 session](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10667) on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

There is now (since a while back) another alternative to this problem: Unlisted app distribution

https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/

It makes it possible to publish your app on the App Store, but the only way to find the app is by a direct link.

And an important difference of this to Apple Business Manager is that you can distribute the app to both managed and unmanaged devices which makes it possible to let users buy there own devices.

I think that Unlisted app distribution is pretty new but will become more and more common when Apple now (2022) do not let companies with less than 100 employees renew their Apple Enterprise Developer Programs and force those companies to other distribution models.

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately there is no other way than to subscribe to the Enterprise Program, since it's easier to distribute the App to all the Devices via a URL/Profile. Otherwise you have to manually take all the Devices and export the App via Xcode on the Device (launching the App). Afaik there is minimum requirement of employees. greets